# Coded UI Test - How to change the exe it runs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I created a Coded UI Test from a Microsoft Test Manager recording.  The exe it runs is the one the tester recorded against.

I want this to be a test I run with my build.  How do I change the exe that the coded UI test uses to be the output of:

1. The TFS Build when a TFS Build is being run
2. The local build when the test is being run on my machine.

I do NOT need help adding my Coded UI test to my TFS Build.  There are [several great posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/05/26/coded-ui-test-in-a-team-build.aspx) on [that already](http://intovsts.net/2010/01/21/running-coded-ui-tests-from-action-recordings-with-mtlm-in-team-builds-tfs2010/).

I don't have `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch`. I have `this.UIMap.StartApplication();` which then runs generated code (in CodedUI.Designer.cs).  [Best Practices for Coded UI tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380782.aspx) says "Do not edit the UIMap.designer.cs file directly. If you do so, the changes to the file will be overwritten."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a build configuration to the test project.  In that configuration, add a preprocessor definition, PRIVATE_BUILD.

Then, you can use #IFDEF to determine which build to launch:

```
#ifdef PRIVATE_BUILD
ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(pathToPrivateBuild, "", args);
#else
ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(pathToOfficialBuild, "", args);
#endif // PRIVATE_BUILD
```

Make sure you don't add that local-only configuration as a flavor for TFS to build during the official build.

Comment: I don't have `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch`.  I have `this.UIMap.StartApplication();` which then runs generated code.  I would rather not change generated code.

Comment: In the MS Best Practices for Coded UI tests it says "Do not edit the UIMap.designer.cs file directly. If you do so, the changes to the file will be overwritten."

Comment: OK, I am dumb.  Just replace `this.UIMap.StartApplication();` with `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch`.

Comment: Everyone kept telling me "just use ApplicationUnderTest.Launch", but heard: "Change the parameter of ApplicationUnderTest.Launch".  Sad that I had to waste 200 points cause I can't read.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you until now :)

Depending on which version of VS you have (probably not 2010), you may be able to have custom code in the UI map.

In 2010 they now create a partial class, one half of which is created by the designer, the other half is custom, and can be edited.  You can copy/paste macros from the generated code into the custom code, remove the reference from the XML file (since in 2010 macros are XML-ized first), and regenerate the code safely and cleanly.

Comment: Also, you could use a custom environment variable, and have the path that AUT.Launch specifies contain that variable.  When it gets expanded in the different environments, it can point to different locations.  AUT.Launch("%envVar%..., in this case, being inside the generated code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Coded UI Test Editor in Visual Studio Feature Pack 2 to visually update the parameter without any coding.

See the following blog post for a tutorial and info on obtaining the extension: http://windotnet.blogspot.com/#!/2011/07/coded-ui-test-editor-is-visual-studio.html

-Paul