# TFS Team Build Coded UI Tests using Test Agent with Windows Form App - TestInitialize - launching the application

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests

If I want tests to run against a Windows Forms application that is built using a team build and then will pass the build process to a test agent to run coded UI tests, can anyone enlighten me as to a good way to ensure that before the Coded UI tests run, that the application that has just been built is executed on the test agent machine so that the tests can run against it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch`

Check these SO questions:

- [Coded UI Test - How to change the exe it runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745073/coded-ui-test-how-to-change-the-exe-it-runs)
- [VS 2010 Coded UI Test - Launch Referenced Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776774/vs-2010-coded-ui-test-launch-referenced-application)
- [Starting an application with coded UI tests in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136628/starting-an-application-with-coded-ui-tests-in-vs-2010)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this is very helpful. I am linking the msdn documentation for this class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.applicationundertest.aspx